# Sorting maps Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, treemap, sortedmap

I have a hashmap of values, which are objects and keys, which are names of objects (names are unique). The objects contain a lot of variables and I would like to sort a map, using one of them. So far there's no problem, but thing is that those values might be the same for 2 or more objects, so program would overwrite them. In the situation of 'collision' I would like to sort those pairs which has the same key by some other key and so on, until I sort them in alphabetical order.
I've tried to create a structure, but it's not correct, cause it's sorting alphabetically no matter what.

```
SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<String, SomeClass>>>> myMap;
```

Could you please help me a bit? Is that what I have figured out at least close to the result? :)
Thanks!

Edit:

```
SortedMap<String, AbstractEventActivityClass> mapNameObject = new TreeMap<>();
SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<String, AbstractEventActivityClass>> byDisLikes = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<String, AbstractEventActivityClass>>> byLikes new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<Integer, SortedMap<String, AbstractEventActivityClass>>>> subscribers = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

SomeClass:

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
String name;
UserClass user;
int likes, dislikes, noSubscribers;

public SomeClass(String name, UserClass user){
    this.name = name;
    this.user = user;
    this.likes = 0;
    this.dislikes = 0;
    this.noSubscribers = 0;
}
```

Add Object:

```
void addObject(String name, String description, UserClass user){
    SomeClass object = new SomeClass(name, user);
    this.mapNameObject.put(name, object);
    Integer noDislikes = Integer.valueOf(object.dislikes);
    this.byDisLikes.put(noDislikes, this.mapNameObject);

    Integer noLikes = Integer.valueOf(object.likes);
    this.byLikes.put(noLikes, this.byDisLikes);

    Integer noSubs = Integer.valueOf(object.noSubscribers);
    this.subscribers.put(noSubs, this.byLikes);
}
```

Comment: Could you post some small and executable code? We will be able to understand better.

Comment: Can you share the structure of `SomeClass`, and some examples of how you'd want them sorted?

Comment: I edited my post :)

Comment: why are you using maps inside maps inside maps... its so confusing. Isn't it clearer to create just one map with a custom implemented Comparator which orders the objects the way you want?

Comment: Create a comparator and then create a sorted map that use this comparator, or create a sorted collection of `SomeClass` objects and use the comparator to sort this collection => https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html